# Why did Metatron receive 60 lashes?

Tags: reward-punishment, malach-angel, agada-stories-legends, tractate-chagiga

In the story of the 4 who entered Pardes (Chagigah starting on 14b) it says that Elisha ben Abuyah saw Metatron the angel sitting and therefore became a heretic. In order to show Elisha that Metatron is not an independent power the angel was given 60 lashes of fire. My questions are:

1. What is the symbolism (if any) with the number 60? Usually a human is given up to 39 lashes.
2. Does this gemarah imply that an angel feels pain? If not what was the point in lashing him at all?

Comment: Given that Babylonia used base 60, 60 probably just means a lot; akin to saying "a hundred" or "hundreds" in a base 10 society.

Comment: @mevaqesh - That seems about right. As for #2, I don't think the lashes were given as a punishment to Metatron; the Gemara clearly states it was to show that Metatron had no authority, which you mentioned yourself! I'm not sure I entirely understand what you are asking.

Comment: There's another instance in the end of Yoma where an angel (Gavriel) was given Malkos.

Comment: @mevaqesh do you have a link that you can show Bablyonians using base 60? just curious

Comment: @Trust it is common knowledge. Just Google it and I am sure you will find it in a moment.

Comment: The Maharsha addresses  this question